# How to query using multiple tables and filter

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

[image]

I would like to create a view where I can see the EventID, EventName, City.
For my scenario, let's say I don't want to see events that user 4 has already reserved. So the expected result would be:

[image]

How can this be achieved using sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM EventsTable
    WHERE EventsTable.Id NOT IN
    (SELECT ReservationsTable.EventId FROM ReservationsTable WHERE ReservationsTable.UserID = 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
Select DISCTINT ET.EventID, ET.EventName, ET.City 
FROM ReservationsTable RT RIGHT JOIN EventsTable ET 
ON RT.EventID=ET.EventID
WHERE RT.UserID <> 4
```